# Access updated/inserted values using CLR tiggers

Tags: c#, .net, triggers, clr, sqlclient

I have a requirement of getting updated/inserted values in SQL server 2008 using CLR method. I read on net that “trigger is meant for validation also”, But I am not getting how to get the incoming values ( before or after update/insert) to the SQL server using .net assembly System.Data.SqlClient , SqlDataReader method.
Is it possible to get the updated/inserted values using dll ?

Please help me.

Comment: You could always [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/ms131093(SQL.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (triggContext.IsUpdatedColumn(colno).ToString() = True ) means then it indicates that the column is updated/inserted. Then I can get the values using sqlComm.ExecuteReader(colno).